# Is there a way to detect that I'm during a CollectionChanged event in ObservableCollection?

Tags: c#, observablecollection

Ok, So I'm getting the famous error:
"Cannot change ObservableCollection during a CollectionChanged event"
when I try to remove from an ObservableCollection.

```
SelectedItems.Remove(oldItem);
```

I want to achieve something like this:

```
If (SelectedItems_During_A_Collection_Changed_Event == false)
 SelectedItems.Remove(oldItem);
```

Because I want to run the mentioned line in cases when I'm not during a collection changed event, and there are a lot of cases of that kind.

Any suggestion, please?

Comment: Can you put a lock statement in?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a state variable that you set at the beginning of the collection changed event and clear it at the end.
An alternative would be to inspect the stack trace but that is not something I would do myself.